# Prove that it is possible to isolate $z$ as a function of $(x,y)$ in $x^2 z^2-z^3 y x=0$ near the point $(1,1,1)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Prove that it is possible to isolate $z$ as a function of $(x,y)$ in $x^2 z^2-z^3 y x=0$ near the point $(1,1,1)$, but not near the origin.

I just need the idea for start, cause its supposed to be a maximum/minimum problem but i am totally lost, any hint will be well received.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Do you know about [implicit function theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem)? Also, please use MathJax to render the math correctly by adding `$...$` to your math expressions.

Comment: Oh, i get it, thank u so much